# Macro to loop through all sheets in the workbook, test if a cell has a certain value. If yes, copy the sheet and exit the loop

Tags: excel, vba, macos

```
Dim j As Double
For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Sheets(j).Range("E4").Value Like "Filters" Then
            ActiveSheet.Copy before:=Worksheets(1)
              ActiveSheet.Name = "data"
        End If
 Next j
```

This is my code... when i run the code worksheet is created as "Data" but it is not exiting the loop... it is creating duplication of "data" worksheet and getting debug.. im missing very small thing  and i dont know what it is.. can anybody help.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is to stop the loop once the sheet has been copied, change your code to this:

```
Dim j As Double
For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Sheets(j).Range("E4").Value Like "Filters" Then
            ActiveSheet.Copy before:=Worksheets(1)
              ActiveSheet.Name = "data"
              Exit For 'Or could be Exit Sub?
        End If
 Next j
```

Comment: @KesavanAnnamalai could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped you? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub poiuyt()
Dim j As Long
For j = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    With Sheets(j)
        If  .Range("E4").Value Like "Filters" Then
            .Copy before:=Worksheets(1)
            .Name = "data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
 Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much